# Rails 3.2 Postgres Save Error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: Syntax error near 'T' at position 5"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, syntax-error

My app has started throwing errors when I try to save a particular class to the database.  I'm not sure exactly what caused this to start happening - I've been having all kinds of database issues for the last few days....

In any case, my model seems to be working fine (it is properly calculating all of the before_save values), but then it tries to save to the database and blows up.

```
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "portfolios" ("correlation_matrix", "created_at", "data", "mean_return", "std_dev", "updated_at", "weights") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["correlation_matrix", "--- \n- - 1.0\n  - -0.4873114574375062\n- - -0.4873114574375062\n  - 1.0\n"], ["created_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 15:12:35 MDT -06:00], ["data", {"TSX"=>0.5, "VUSTX"=>0.5}], ["mean_return", #<BigDecimal:7fadb119b750,'0.488052381E-1',18(45)>], ["std_dev", #<BigDecimal:7fadb119b598,'0.7668705159 123244E-1',18(45)>], ["updated_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 15:12:35 MDT -06:00], ["weights", "--- \nTSX: 0.5\nVUSTX: 0.5\n"]]
```

Throws this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  Syntax error near 'T' at position 5
```

I have no idea what this error means (or what this 'T' is.....), or even where to begin troubleshooting it.... Any help would be appreciated.

I can post whatever information might be necessary to figure this out....

Relevant migration:

```
  create_table :portfolios do |t|
    t.text :weights
    t.decimal :mean_return, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
    t.decimal :std_dev, :precision => 15, :scale => 10
    t.text :correlation_matrix
    t.hstore :data

    t.timestamps
  end

  execute "CREATE INDEX portfolios_gin_data_hstore ON portfolios USING GIN(data);"
```

Full stack trace:

```
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  Syntax error near 'T' at position 5
: INSERT INTO "portfolios" ("correlation_matrix", "created_at", "data", "mean_return", "std_dev", "updated_at", "weights") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4,     $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1164:in `get_last_result'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1164:in `exec_cache'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:665:in `block in exec_query'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.    rb:20:in `instrument'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:663:in `exec_query'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:63:in `exec_insert'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:90:in `insert'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:14:in `insert'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/relation.rb:66:in `insert'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:363:in `create'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:57:in `create'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `block in     create'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in     `_run__772785567275930853__create__1186465801021498362__callbacks'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in     `__run_callback'
... 11 levels...
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in     `save'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2     levels) in save'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in     with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.    6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in     `transaction'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in     `with_transaction_returning_status'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in     save'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in     `rollback_active_record_state!'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
  from (irb):33
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@myapp/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE 1**
Some model code as requested.

macro stuff:

```
attr_accessible :weights

serialize :correlation_matrix
serialize :weights

has_and_belongs_to_many :securities, :uniq => true
has_and_belongs_to_many :efficient_frontiers

before_validation :format_weights_tickers, :add_securities, :validate_weights, :set_weights_in_hstore, :build_correlation_matrix, :set_mean_return, :set_standard_deviation

validates_presence_of :mean_return, :std_dev, :securities, :correlation_matrix, :weights
validates_numericality_of :mean_return, :std_dev

validate :uniqueness_of_weights 

before_destroy :check_for_dependent

scope :by_std_dev, :order => 'std_dev ASC'
```

anything and everything I can find to do with the HStore column
*all I really use HStore for is for a search on specific tickers.  This used to work... I don't know what changed.  I might have upgraded Postgres (I was fiddling around with homebrew) or potentially something changed with rails.  I did try going back to 3.2.3 but I got the same error.*

```
def self.find_by_hstore(search_key, search_value)  
  where("data @> (:key => :value)", :key => search_key.to_s, :value => search_value.to_s)
end  

def set_weights_in_hstore
  self.data = {} if self.data.nil?
  weights.each_pair {|ticker, weight| self.data[ticker.to_s] = weight}
end
```

I can post the entirety of the model if this is too disjointed.   Let me know!

**UPDATE #2 - I am getting similar errors elsewhere also....**

After a simple user signup....

```
SQL (10.9ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "data", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_email_at", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "plan", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "selected_portfolio_id", "sign_in_count", "unconfirmed_email", "updated_at", "verified") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23) RETURNING "id"  [["admin", false], ["confirmation_sent_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 20:37:07 MDT -06:00], ["confirmation_token", "7Xu15pMrV9zTNmofv8bD"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["created_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 20:37:07 MDT -06:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["data", {"min_rebalance_spacing"=>90 days, "max_contact_frequency"=>7 days, "allowable_drift"=>5}], ["email", "joe@what.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$HNUmlYmcVXbBsyZRFCAB7e8c5mf6S9UOdWr/ZCz10y5Sg4gOh8Zvq"], ["last_email_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 20:37:07 MDT -06:00], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["name", "Joe Blow"], ["plan", "basic"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["selected_portfolio_id", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["unconfirmed_email", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 16 Jun 2012 20:37:07 MDT -06:00], ["verified", false]]

20:37:07 log.1          | [ef4a7d55fb30e8fb82ac6c860e674bfc] [127.0.0.1] PG::Error: ERROR:  Syntax error near 'm' at position 5

20:37:07 log.1          | : INSERT INTO "users" ("admin", "confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "data", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_email_at", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "name", "plan", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "selected_portfolio_id", "sign_in_count", "unconfirmed_email", "updated_at", "verified") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23) RETURNING "id"
```

**UDPATE 3**

There appears to be something funky going on with my database / user table.  I get the following error during loading the environment in a migration:

```
rake aborted!
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,         a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: I'd guess it is the "T" in "TSX". What does your model class look like?

Comment: It is fairly large... not sure exactly what to post.  Do you have any thoughts for what the issue could be? Then I could post some relevant code....  The TSX bits always show up in strings, so what could be the issue?  Something with HStore?

Comment: Alernatively, is it having trouble with "["std_dev", #<BigDecimal:7fadb119b598,'0.7668705159 123244E-1',18(45)>]" ?? That is what is in position #5.... but this is just a plain jane number in a decimal database column... Arg! (What is with the space between xxx159 and 123244? though?)

Comment: The macros in the model would be useful (`serialize`, `has_many`, and that sort of thing); I'm guessing that you're doing something to screw up the `hstore` format. The space in `159 123244` is just inspect output, don't pay it too much attention.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Sorry... weather was nice so got outside for a few hours :)  I'll post some more of the code in an update.

Comment: I seem to be getting this problem elsewhere too... see update #2

Comment: You are using https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore right?

Comment: Yeah.  I have also dropped, re-created, and re-migrated the database.  So I'm 99% sure the HStore extension has been run.  That being said, HStore doesn't appear to be part of the issue for the second error (my user model does have an HStore attribute, but that's not what was throwing the error.  Maybe I should try messing with my models and rip out HStore... see what happens?)

Comment: Added some more details re: postgres errors...

Comment: Solved via @tomtaylor's suggestion.  Thank you very much for all your help though

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I just had a similar problem, on Rails 3.2. If you're not using Rails trunk (working towards 4.0), it doesn't understand the hstore natively - you need to define a serialization coder (which is provided by the `activerecord-postgres-hstore` gem), like so:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore
end
```

Comment: THIS WAS IT!  Thanks!!  I have no idea why this broke all of a sudden.  I had been using Rails 3.2.3 for some time with no errors.  I upgraded to 3.2.6 and it blew up.  I've been using the activerecord-postgres-hstore gem teh entire time... oh well.

Comment: This problem seems to be related to prepared statements. I had the same problem and if I disable prepared statements (using `prepared_statements: false` in `database.yml`) it works again, even without `serialize`.