# Invalid statement with Postgres hstore and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, hstore

I am using the activerecord-postgres-hstore gem with rails 3.2. I have setup hstore and when I try and save any data I get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ProductsController#create

PG::Error: ERROR:  Syntax error near 'a' at position 4
: INSERT INTO "products" ("created_at", "name", "price", "properties", "updated_at")      
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"
```

In this case I have 'properties' defined as an hstore data type. I have seen this error with both postgresl 8.4 and 9.1. Any info appreciated.

Comment: What values are you trying to insert? There is nothing wrong with the query, maybe it's the data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3.2 Postgres Save Error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: Syntax error near 'T' at position 5"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067120/rails-3-2-postgres-save-error-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error). Sounds like a duplicate at least and hopefully the answer applies here as well.

Comment: I did see that stackoverflow post and tryed adding the line   serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore to my model, but that did not help. Here is a little more detail from the console when I try and do the insert... https://gist.github.com/2995637

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the code " serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore" from [Rails 3.2 Postgres Save Error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: Syntax error near 'T' at position 5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067120/rails-3-2-postgres-save-error-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error) solved my issue. I just had the wrong model name when I initially tried this as a fix.

Comment: I added this and in console it works fine but when I visit my site in the browser it has an error in the routes `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore)`.

Comment: Be sure you have the hstore extension for postgres installed.