# Dynamic Forms with HStore and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I was following [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms), and finished the tutorial. Everything was working fine. Then I decided to use hstore instead of a serialized hash, and after setting up hstore, ran into a error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR: Syntax error near '!' at position 4 : INSERT INTO "products" ("product_type_id", "created_at", "properties", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

I googled, and found a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067120/rails-3-2-postgres-save-error-activerecordstatementinvalid-pgerror-error), but I'm using Rails 4, which supposedly doesn't need to use that gem anymore.

Here's my code:

The relevant portion of my form.html.haml looks like this

```
= f.fields_for :properties, OpenStruct.new(@product.properties) do |builder|
  - @product.product_type.products.each do |product|
    = render "products/fields/#{product.field_type}", field: field, f: builder
```

My Product model looks like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product_type
  serialize :properties
end
```

I can post more code if it will help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have to use `serialize` at all with hstore in Rails4? I haven't used it but I thought hstore was natively understood by the Rails4 PostgreSQL driver so `serialize` kludgery was no longer needed. The `!` in the error message would show up in YAML and that's what `serialize` uses by default.

Comment: @muistooshort, That actually fixed the problem. Will you put that as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails4 PostgreSQL driver for ActiveRecord is supposed to have native support for PostgreSQL's `hstore` type so you shouldn't need to use `serialize` at all. Try ditching the `serialize`.

BTW, a `!` will appear in a YAML string when you attempt to serialize some objects to YAML:

```
"--- !ruby/object:SomeClassName ..."
```

and that `!` could cause some problems if PostgreSQL was expecting to see an `hstore` string.